# C# ODBC get value of declared variable after query has executed

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, odbc

Trying to see if there's a method by which I could get the value of `object_name` from the following query. Printing the variable name doesn't output anything. I've tried `odbcdatareader` and `execute.scalar`, but nothing is returned.

```
DECLARE
      @object_name SYSNAME
    , @object_id INT
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
      @object_name = '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.[object_id]) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) + ']'
    , @object_id = [object_id]
FROM(SELECT[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ARSTREAM', 'U')) o

print @object_name
```

```
void main()
{
   OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
   OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();
   OdbcDataReader dr;
   conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=" + Form3.comboBox1.Text + ";UID=" + luid + ";pwd=" + lpwd;
   conn.Open();
   command.Connection = conn;
   command.CommandText = sqlq;  //see sql query above
   command.Parameters.Add("@object_name", query);  
   var outp = command.ExecuteScalar();
   dr = command.ExecuteReader();
   while (dr.Read())
   {
       column = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
   }
   dr.Close();
   conn.Close();
}
```

I tried the code shown, however all I'm getting is NULL. I suspect there's way to load the variable information from the server, but I just don't know if its a parameter or some other way you have to enumerate it. I tagging this as both SQL server and Oracle, because ODBC is not specific to either and I will be using both database servers.

Comment: For `ExecuteScalar()` to function you need to `SELECT @object_name`.  If your solely working with SQL Server then using `SqlConnection()` rather than `OdbcConnection()` is probably going to be easier in the long run.

Comment: You don't the the `@SQL` parameter in the C# code. `@SQL` is a local variable declared and used in the command batch.

Comment: Why have you tagged both SQL server and oracle?

Comment: Why assign the values to variables at all? You don't do anything with the variables afterwards.

Comment: I will be using both SQL Server and Oracle database servers, so I'm trying to use the more universal way of connecting to the database servers so I don't have code everthing twice.

Comment: Your tsql code is unlikely to work in oracle though

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the @object_name = from the query, I get the value I need. Thanks for everyone's efforts!

```
DECLARE
      @object_name SYSNAME
    , @object_id INT
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.[object_id]) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) + ']'
    , @object_id = [object_id]
FROM(SELECT[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ARSTREAM', 'U')) o
```